# How to safely display user's text containing all html/css in rails 3

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3, security

I want user to be able to paste their html/css code? eg. from internet.
How to safely display user's text containing all html/css in rails 3 without security risks and also interfering with site's html/css (iframe?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails (since Rails 3.0) will do this automatically for you. Calling `#html_safe` on a string will do the opposite.

Edit: There's a plugin called [WhiteList](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/whitelist) which will do just that.

Comment: yes but I need to display all user's html/css tags/code. html_safe does that but it's not really safe. So?

Comment: I thought about sanitize method but it doesn't want to play with html_safe/raw